# Explicit Instantiation of Template

Tags: c++, templates

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) has been really helpful, but I still have questions about this process that don't appear to be answered.

To what extent must I explicitly instantiate a template? For example, if in my definitions file I am using templates on every function, friend class, operator overload, etc, must I instantiate each in a template instantiation file (the current method that I am using)?

Based off of my trial and error, the answer appears to be no, and that a simple

```
template class Class<type>;
```

will work for all of the class's members. However, I have read code that suggests otherwise, and a concrete answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might find [this post](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/22/source-organization-of-templates/) helpful.

Answer (score 5):

In general you don't need to explicitly *instantiate* a template, but just define it in a header file and include that header file. However, a common application of explicit template instantiation is when you want to "hide" the definition of a template. Imagine the following situation, in which for simplicity we hide the implementation of a template function:

***header.h***

```
template<class X> void f(); // declaration
```

***header.cpp***

```
#include "header.h"

template<class X> void f(){ /* definition */ }
template void f<int>();    // explicit instantiation for int, force the compiler to generate code
template void f<double>(); // explicit instantiation for double, same
```

***main.cpp***

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    f<int>(); // OK
    f<double>(); // also OK
    f<char>(); // linker error
}
```

As you can see, the function `f` is defined in the `header.cpp` file (and **not** in `header.h`), and therefore the implementation is hidden from the user. Because of the explicit instantiations for `int` and `double`, the compiler will be able to find the code of `f<int>()` and `f<double>();` when compiling `main.cpp`. However, when trying to find the code for `f<char>();` when compiling `main.cpp`, we get a linker error. That's because the compilation is done independently, and when the compiler compiles `header.cpp`, the compiler only generates code for `f<int>` and `f<double>`, and doesn't know we will invoke `f<char>` so it does not generate code for `f<char>`.

The only catch is that in order to make use of such a code hiding, we *must* explicitly instantiate the function for all the types for which we want to use it, otherwise we get linker errors.