# Why is explicit instantiaion of template function nothing working

Tags: c++, templates

### Problem Description

We have the following files:

`RetrieveValues.hpp`:

```
Class RetrieveValues {
public:
  RetrieveValues(){}

  template<typename Comp>  
  static int getMinAmount(){...}
};
```

`RetrieveValues.cpp` we have:

```
template RetrieveValues::<std::less<int>>getMinAmount(){...}
```

`ComputeAmounts.cpp`

```
int x = RetrieveValues::getMinAmount();
```

I followed the same as in the following question [Explicit Instantiation of Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707522/explicit-instantiation-of-template)
 and I got the following error **error: explicit instantiation of non-template RetrieveValues**. how do I fix this explicit instantiation? I Just need `getMinAmount()` to be template.

Comment: You mix explicit instantiation with specialization, while you probably want both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit instantiation looks like this:

```
template
int RetrieveValues::getMinAmount<std::less<int>>();
```

You forgot the return type. `RetrieveValues::getMinAmount` is the fully qualified name of the function. Then comes the type you want to instantiate (`std::less<int>`). Explicit instantiation doesn't have a function body.

Here is an example:

```
#include <functional>

class RetrieveValues {
public:
  RetrieveValues(){}

  template<typename Comp>  
  static int getMinAmount() { return 0; }
};

template
int RetrieveValues::getMinAmount<std::less<int>>();

int main() {
    int x = RetrieveValues::getMinAmount<std::less<int>>();
}
```

If you want to specialize it's:

```
template<>
int RetrieveValues::getMinAmount<std::less<int>>() { return 1; }
```

You have to add `<>` after `template` and add a function body.

Here is an example:

```
#include <functional>

class RetrieveValues {
public:
  RetrieveValues(){}

  template<typename Comp>  
  static int getMinAmount() { return 0; }
};

template<>
int RetrieveValues::getMinAmount<std::less<int>>() { return 1; }

int main() {
    int x = RetrieveValues::getMinAmount<std::less<int>>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas for the Answer and Explanation. Thanks a lot